# Pandas - Based on top x% value of each column, Mark as new number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, quantile, percentile

I have a pandas dataframe below:

```
    df

    name    value    
0   Jack       3      
1   Luke       3      
2   Mark       2      
3   Chris      1      
4   Ace        10
5   Isaac      8
```

Based on the "value" column, I want to have the top 50% value to be marked as 1, bottom 50% value marked as 0.

Expecting to get result below:

```
    Results

    name    value      percent mark  
0   Jack       3            0
1   Luke       4            1
2   Mark       2            0
3   Chris      1            0
4   Ace        10           1
5   Isaac      8            1
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: 50% being the mean.

Comment: Yes. But I just use 50% as example, I would like to do 25% or x% as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare a series with its median and then convert `bool` to `int`:

```
df['percent_mark'] = (df['value'] > df['value'].median()).astype(int)
```

For a specific percentage, use [`pd.Series.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.quantile.html). For example:

```
df['percent_mark'] = (df['value'] > df['value'].quantile(0.25)).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `numpy` which is maybe faster

```
import numpy as np
df['percent_mark_50'] = np.where(df.value > df.value.median(), 1, 0)
```

Or

```
df['percent_mark_25'] = np.where(df.value > np.percentile(df.value, 25), 1, 0)
```